# Installing Node in a linux grid server

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell, web-hosting

So some background, I'm installing Node on a host server, but it's a grid server not a server that's solely for my website.

The grid server doesn't have a root user/ administrative powers. So to install node I found this workaround: http://iantearle.com/blog/media-temple-grid-and-nodejs . It's a Linux Grid server, I've never used Linux so if someone could explain to me what the commands mean, especially: `./configure --prefix=~/opt/`

Lastly I followed the steps but when I try to run the `node` command in the server it says `node:command not found` - which is why I'm trying to understand the steps. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the process:

1. Configure

The configure script is responsible for getting ready to build the software on your specific system. It makes sure all of the dependencies for the rest of the build and install process are available, and finds out whatever it needs to know to use those dependencies.

Unix programs are often written in C, so we’ll usually need a C compiler to build them. In these cases the configure script will establish that your system does indeed have a C compiler, and find out what it’s called and where to find it.

2. Make

Once configure has done its job, we can invoke make to build the software. This runs a series of tasks defined in a Makefile to build the finished program from its source code.

The tarball you download usually doesn’t include a finished Makefile. Instead it comes with a template called Makefile.in and the configure script produces a customised Makefile specific to your system.

3.Make Install

Now that the software is built and ready to run, the files can be copied to their final destinations. The make install command will copy the built program, and its libraries and documentation, to the correct locations.

`--prefix=~/opt/` -> will set the build directory to `/home/yourhome/opt` directory.

Now if you didnt get errors while doing those 3 steps explained above make sure you did the following:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
export PATH=~/opt/bin:${PATH}
```

nano is a text editor and you are opening `.bash_profile` file with it.
you need to add `export PATH=~/opt/bin:${PATH}` in that file and save it using ctrl+x

Then restart your terminal.

Specified github repository for nodejs is outdated. use the [following link](https://github.com/nodejs/node) instead.

```
git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git
```

P.S `node:command not found` usually happens when the program is not installed correctly or it's executable isnt in your terminal's `PATH` variable.

Comment: Thanks so much Farhad, your explanations totally made sense and now that I understood I believe Node did install and it's just the that executable isn't in the $PATH variable. I `echo $PATH` and it's looking into the created `opt` directory. But actually when I CD' ed into that directory manually there's nothing there.  -- `echo $PATH` gives me : `/home/12345/users/.home/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` but theres no `bin` in opt.

Comment: also I'm not sure why it's looking into a directory called `games`. I see a node folder, do you suggest I change the PATH? I tried following the steps again to see if anything would change and nothing did PATH is still this and there still isn't anythin in `opt`

Comment: Try this : which node   Post the output

Comment: nothing appears :/. I also tried `which -a node` and still nothing

Comment: Ok, remove node directory that you cloned from github by `rm -rf node` , then clone this repository: `git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git`  Node has moved to its own repository, then use all the other steps as provided in your link, just change the `git clone` step to what i provided. Give me feed back if this fixed your problem.

Comment: So I ran all the commands with the git repo you suggested and it didn't install anyway, but I paid attention to an error that appeared during the `./config` step , it says : `C++ compiler too old, need g++ 4.8 or clang++ 3.4 (CXX=g++)
creating  ./icu_config.gypi
* Using ICU in deps/icu-small
creating  ./icu_config.gypi
` I'm not sure if this is relevant to the rest of the steps not working, since now I know that it's the C compiler that makes the rest work.

Comment: I ran the instructions on a clean installation of debian system and it worked. Is this the only warning/error you get ?

Comment: Hey Farhad, so the other error at the end of the make step, looked something like:  `make: *** [install] Error 2`.  I looked for another work-around and used this instead: http://davidseah.com/2013/07/installing-node-js-on-mediatemple-dv-4/ . I ran a make on an unpacked tar file and I believe it's installed. I can see a node version with `./node --version` and can run the node command with `./node` It didn't make an opt file like the tutorial said but I believe it's installed anyway.

Comment: Farhad thank you for ALL your help!!! I learned a lot and hopefully our back and forth helps others also :)